# Swift Delegation: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift3, delegates, runtime-error, option-type

> **Edit: Please note the question below discusses using delegation between**
>   **2 viewcontrollers that are *also* implemented in a UITabBarController.**

I've done a fair bit of searching here and on YouTube, but haven't seen my issue replicated elsewhere. I'll keep it to the point.

I have 2 view controllers that I coded myself -not generated by XCode-; TabOneController, and TabTwoController

below are the coding for both...

```
import UIKit

class TabOneController: UIViewController{


    private let instanceOfTabOneView = TabOneView()

    var vc1Delegate: fromOneToTwo!

    override func loadView() {

        super.loadView()

            view.addSubview(instanceOfTabOneView.buildTheVu())
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        runThisOnce()

        }

    func runThisOnce(){

        vc1Delegate.passTheValue(heroNameIs: "pass this to TabTwoController")

    }

}

protocol fromOneToTwo{

    func passTheValue(heroNameIs: String)

}
```

as for tab 2...

```
import UIKit

class TabTwoController: UIViewController, fromOneToTwo{


    private let instanceOfTabTwoView = TabTwoView()


    override func loadView() {

        super.loadView()

            view.addSubview(instanceOfTabTwoView.buildTheVu())

        assignDelegateToSelf()

    }

    func assignDelegateToSelf(){

        let instanceTabOne = TabOneController()
            instanceTabOne.vc1Delegate = self

    }

    func passTheValue(heroNameIs:String){

        instanceOfTabTwoView.txtFld.text = heroNameIs

    }

}
```

I'm getting the following error at runtime *-the app builds successfully-*...

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on the following line...

```
vc1Delegate.passTheValue(heroNameIs: "pass this to TabTwoController")
```

When I comment out the above line, the app builds and runs successfully, but of course the app doesn't execute the delegation.

I kinda understand what the compiler is trying to tell me, that the

```
vc1Delegate
```

hasn't been instantiated -I guess-. But I searched under every rock, and can't seem to find how to get around this.

I'd appreciate any help or guidance. Sorry if my code seems immature, I'm new to Swift and programming in general. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In a `UITabBarController`, the first tab is instantiating by default. The view controller initialization executes the `loadView` and finds a `nil` because the second tab did not initialize yet; this is normal behavior. My suggestion is making the delegate weak optional with the `?` suffix and run the delegate code elsewhere. Also, always capitalize the first letter in class and protocol names.

```
weak var vc1Delegate: FromOneToTwo?
```

If this structure is mandatory, try with a custom notification observer instead.

Comment: Appreciate your reply. I will create an Xcode project with 2 regular Viewcontrollers, and replace any UI controls with variables. I'll post another comment if UITabController was the issue. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, your error happens in line `var vc1Delegate: fromOneToTwo!` while you declared this delegate variable as not null but then calling `passTheValue` on it. A correct practice will be

```
var vc1Delegate: fromOneToTwo?

func runThisOnce(){
    if let delegate = vc1Delegate {
        vc1Delegate.passTheValue(heroNameIs: "pass this to TabTwoController")
    }
}
```

Secondly, you are not using delegate correctly. In the `assignDelegateToSelf()` function, you are creating a new instance of `TabOneController`
 and then assign delegate. Instead, you need to find out the existing `TabOneController` instance and assign delegate.

Comment: How does one find out the existing `TabOneController` instance?

Comment: @Sebastian That depends on how your code is written... If you want delegate calls, you have to register delegate for a controller and then you can only receive delegate calls from that controller. Normally, if you use storyboard and normal segue to new view controllers, you do not need to care about this because you will only have one instance of the view controller. However, when you create view controller programmatically (like calling initialed from storyboard function), then you need to initiate only once and store that instant somewhere so that you can find it out later and receive calls.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I was able to do it by saving the current viewcontroller class in a variable when the segue is triggered, and then passing that variable to the other view controller during the segue

Answer (score 0):

I try this and worked add `delegate = self` in table cellforRowAt
like this

```swift
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
 {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChapterPracticeTableViewCell") as! ChapterPracticeTableViewCell

        cell.deligate = self
        return cell
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing. Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. That way future users can benefit more from your answer and you increase the chance to get upvotes. Please edit to add further details, especially an explanation why and how this work. You can find more information on [how to write good answers in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).